# Group by return correct name for a max value in another field

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

Sorry for the poorly titled question but I have the following example data:

```
Account ID     Name     Order Value
1122           John      2000
1122           Dave      1500
```

For many 000's of accounts (in my learning example). What i am trying to do is group by account ID's to return the max order value from each account, *but i am also interested in who made that order for each account id*.

I am doing that as follows:

```
SELECT Data.[Account ID], min(Data.Name), max(Data.[Order Value])

group by Data.[Account ID]
```

However this returns Dave (due to the min() function), against the Order value of 2000 where as I'd like to see John's name. How can I get the name associated with the max order value for each account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a correlated subquery within a `where not exists` clause:

```
select d.* from data d
where not exists 
(
    select 1 from data t where
    t.[Account ID]  = d.[Account ID] and 
    t.[Order Value] > d.[Order Value]
)
```

Note that:

- `t` & `d` are aliases to allow `Data` to be referenced twice within the same query.
- `select 1` is purely for optimisation: we don't care what the subquery returns, just that it has records (or in this case, doesn't have records).

---

Alternatively, you can calculate the maximums using your current method and simply join the result to the original dataset, e.g.:

```
select d.* from data d inner join
(
    select t.[Account ID], max(t.[Order Value]) as mov
    from data t
    group by t.[Account ID]
) q on
d.[Account ID]  = q.[Account ID] and 
d.[Order Value] = q.mov
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical top 1 per group question. You can't solve it with aggregation only.

One option uses an anti-`left join`:

```
select d.*
from [Data] d
left join [Data] d1 
    on  (d1.[Account ID] = d.[Account ID])
    and (d1.[Order Value] > d.[Order Value])
where d1.[Account ID] is null
```

This phrases as: get the record(s) for which no other record exists with the same account and a greater order value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think "group by".  Think "filter".  You want to get the complete row with the maximum order value.

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.order_value = (select max(t2.order_value)
                       from t as t2
                       where t2.account_id = t.account_id
                      );
```